# Python: use of map equivalent?

Tags: python

I see the following code:

```
>>> [(x, y) for x in [1,2,3] for y in [3,1,4] if x != y] 
[(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 1), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 4)]
```

I also see:

```
squares = list(map(lambda x: x**2, range(10)))
squares = [x**2 for x in range(10)]
```

How can I accomplish the first list comprehension using lambda functions like the bottom code?

Comment: I don't think there'a a `map` equivalent to multiple `for` in the list comprehension.

Comment: Also, `map()` can't do conditions like `if x != y`

Comment: Why would you want that?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but you can use `filter()` with a lambda to remove tuples where the items are equal.

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.product()` to get all the `x` and `y` combinations, and `filter()` to skip `x == y`.

There's no need for `map()` in this case, since `itertools.product()` already creates the tuples.

```
result = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] != x[1], itertools.product([1, 2, 3], [3, 1, 4])))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need either a lambda (anonymous) function or mapping of a function to values, if your very simple and still *readable* list comprehension with the beautiful if-condition does its job perfectly fine?

Keep it simple, keep it good.

---

If you insist on **map** and **lambda** for your specific example, you could do (and shouldn't):

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [3,1,4]
>>> [l for l in map(lambda o,p: (o,p) if o!=p else [], [i for j in [a,a[1::2],a[::-2],a[::-1]] for i in j], [d for c in [[k,k,k] for k in b] for d in c])if l]
[(1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 1), (3, 1), (3, 4), (2, 4), (1, 4)]
```

or

```
>>> list(filter(lambda o: o[0]!=o[1], zip([i for j in [a,a[1::2],a[::-2],a[::-1]] for i in j], [d for c in [[k,k,k] for k in b] for d in c])))
[(1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 1), (3, 1), (3, 4), (2, 4), (1, 4)]
```

However, this is obviously nonsense and good only to play around. And yes, you can make it even more complicated if you like, by replacing a and b with functional representations of themselves within the list <s>comprehension</s> extension. And yes again, if you had variable lengths of input lists, this could be done as well - even more unreadable.